# Object bevel is "frozen" for part of curve and doesn't adjust with z-axis changes?

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel, path, nurbs-surface

I added a path and gave it an object bevel, everything seemed to be going well until I tried making a z-axis change to part of my path. The bevel tilted around the curve to accommodate this change but a particular point of the path seems to be "frozen" so I get a tear between the tilted and untitled parts:

[image]

The green outlines the segment that I raised on the z-axis, the bevel along the curve tilts to accommodate this change up to the points that I've outlined in red.

Here's a GIF of what's happening:

[image]

It looks to me like everything is adjusting as I raise the segment that I'm working on, everything that is except for the part of the path nearest the viewer. Why is this part staying frozen while everything else is moving to accommodate my z-axis change?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

just use "z-up" on your path:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I actually liked/wanted the tilting/twisting of the bevel that's triggered by dragging upwards - I just didn't want it to stop abruptly at some apparently arbitrary part of the track as it currently seems to. Setting the _Twist Method_ like this disables the x-axis tilting that I actually want. But I've learned something - thanks for pointing out this option. Perhaps I should use it and then manually adjust the tilt at each control point to get exactly the effect I want.